# Does `SERIAL PRIMARY KEY` create two indexes on the table?

Tags: mysql

Since [`SERIAL` is shorthand for `BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-overview.html), it looks like `SERIAL PRIMARY KEY` doubles up on the `UNIQUE` and `PRIMARY KEY`:

```
> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE foo (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY);

> SHOW CREATE TABLE foo \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: foo
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `foo` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
)
```

There's definitely the *wtf* factor of seeing both `PRIMARY KEY` and `UNIQUE KEY id` in `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, but is that really two physical indexes I'm seeing?

Should one avoid using `PRIMARY KEY` with `SERIAL` and instead opt for writing `bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY`, or using `SERIAL` with no primary keys on the table?

Comment: Ugh!  File a bug at bugs.mysql.com .

Comment: Yeah, this looks like a mysql bug...

Comment: I'm also seeing this behavior in 5.7.18 MySQL Community Server

Comment: The phenomena does not occur in `10.2.14-MariaDB`.

Comment: This can be regarded as a bug. Its reason is obvious - `auto_increment` must be a key (server error 1075). But the source is somebody's lasiness - there are aliases `serial` and `serial default value`, and there is no alias `serial primary key`...

Answer (score 2):

I'm also seeing this behavior in 5.7.18 MySQL Community Server.

Based on the output from `SHOW INDEX FROM foo` there is a duplicate index being created and maintained:

```
mysql> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE foo (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> show index from foo;
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| foo   |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | id          | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| foo   |          0 | id       |            1 | id          | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Edit:** This also happens for normal tables:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE foo (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> show index from foo;
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| foo   |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | id          | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| foo   |          0 | id       |            1 | id          | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS where TABLE_NAME = 'foo';
+--------------------+-------------------+-----------------+--------------+------------+-----------------+
| CONSTRAINT_CATALOG | CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA | CONSTRAINT_NAME | TABLE_SCHEMA | TABLE_NAME | CONSTRAINT_TYPE |
+--------------------+-------------------+-----------------+--------------+------------+-----------------+
| def                | my_db             | PRIMARY         | my_db        | foo        | PRIMARY KEY     |
| def                | my_db             | id              | my_db        | foo        | UNIQUE          |
+--------------------+-------------------+-----------------+--------------+------------+-----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Does this happen for an ordinary table as well, i.e. `CREATE TABLE foo ...`? If so, what is the content of INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS for the table?

Comment: @Lennart Yes, and I added the contents of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS` that you requested.

Comment: Ok, so then it's not a bug in `SHOW ...`, it does create two constraints.